# How to create Windows 8 style app bar in WPF?

Tags: wpf, appbar

I intended to create a Windows 8 Style App (Metro), but found out there is no support for using dual screen which is a demand for my app.

Now I am redesigning my app as a desktop application in WPF.
But I still like to mimic some nice design features from Windows 8 Apps.

One of the design features is the fly out bars typically used in a Windows 8 style app:

- Bottom App bar for commands
- Top Navigational bar
- Right Charm that is common for all apps

The design they all have in common is a temporary flyout panel that is layered on top of the current window layout.

My question is: How can I create something similar in WPF?

I have no problem to create a main grid with a hidden bottom row that is made visible to display some common command buttons. But it would be nice to have it fly out on top of my standard layout, not squeeze it.

I know it is possible to open a new window on top of the current but that creates a bad code design and is hard to get nice looking. I would prefer to do it in the same window.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cool question! I've actually done the charm bar fairly recently..

ideally what you need is something like

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

 <Grid x:Name="Overlay" Panel.ZIndex="1000" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <!-- This is where your slide out control is going to go -->
  </Grid>

  <!-- Use whatever layout you need -->
  <ContentControl x:Name="MainContent" />

</Grid>
```

Now rather than squeezing the content - the Overlay grid will be on top of it similar to the charm bar! all with XAML

If you have anymore questions about this, give me a shout!

Edit; my Charm implementation - feel free to use for inspriation!

```
public class SlidePanel : ContentControl
    {
        static SlidePanel()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SlidePanel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SlidePanel)));
        }

        public SlidePanel()
        {
            EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(SlidePanel), SlidePanel.MouseEnterEvent,
                                              new RoutedEventHandler(OnLocalMouseEnter));

            EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(SlidePanel), SlidePanel.MouseLeaveEvent,
                                              new RoutedEventHandler(OnLocalMouseLeave));
        }

        #region Mouse Handlers

        private static void OnLocalMouseEnter(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SetExpanded(sender, true);
        }

        private static void OnLocalMouseLeave(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SetExpanded(sender, false);

        }

        private static void SetExpanded(object sender, bool expanded)
        {
            SlidePanel panel = sender as SlidePanel;

            if (panel != null)
            {
                panel.IsExpanded = expanded;
            }
        }

        #endregion Mouse Handlers

        #region Panel Width

        public double PanelWidth
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(PanelWidthProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PanelWidthProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PanelWidth.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PanelWidthProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PanelWidth", typeof(double), typeof(SlidePanel), new UIPropertyMetadata(5.0));

        #endregion Panel Width

        #region Closed Width

        public double ClosedWidth
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(ClosedWidthProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ClosedWidthProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ClosedWidth.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ClosedWidthProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ClosedWidth", typeof(double), typeof(SlidePanel), new UIPropertyMetadata(5.0, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnClosedWidthChange)));

        #endregion Closed Width

        #region Expanded Property

        public bool IsExpanded
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsExpandedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsExpandedProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsExpanded.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsExpandedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IsExpanded", typeof(bool), typeof(SlidePanel), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnExpandedChanged)));


        #endregion Expanded Property

        #region Property Changes

        private static void OnExpandedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewValue == e.OldValue)
                return;

            SlidePanel panel = d as SlidePanel;

            if (panel == null)
                return;

            bool newVal = (bool)e.NewValue;

            panel.IsExpanded = newVal;

            bool expanded = (bool)panel.GetValue(IsExpandedProperty);

            Storyboard widthAnimation = AnimationHelper.CreateDoubleAnimation<SlidePanel>(panel, expanded,
                (p, a) =>
                {
                    a.From = (double)p.GetValue(SlidePanel.ClosedWidthProperty);
                    a.To = (double)p.GetValue(SlidePanel.PanelWidthProperty);
                },
                (p, a) =>
                {
                    a.From = (double)p.GetValue(SlidePanel.WidthProperty);
                    a.To = (double)p.GetValue(SlidePanel.ClosedWidthProperty);
                }, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 300), WidthProperty);

            Timeline opacity = AnimationHelper.DoubleAnimation(0.0, 1.0, expanded,
                                                                      new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 300), OpacityProperty);

            Storyboard.SetTargetName(opacity, panel.Name);

            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(opacity, new PropertyPath(OpacityProperty));

            widthAnimation.Children.Add(opacity);

            widthAnimation.Begin(panel);

        }

        private static void OnClosedWidthChange(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            SlidePanel panel = d as SlidePanel;

            if (panel != null)
                panel.Width = (double)e.NewValue;
        }

        #endregion Property Changes
    }
```

A little trick I found was to have the opacity set to 0 when it wasnt expanded but set the width to 10, this then allows the user to put the mouse at the side of the screen and then it will appear after a second or so..
cheers.

Edit - As requested.. AnimationHelper.

```
  public class AnimationHelper
    {
        public static Timeline DoubleAnimation(double from, double to, bool modifier, TimeSpan duration, DependencyProperty property)
        {
            DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();

            if (modifier)
            {
                animation.From = from;
                animation.To = to;

            }
            else
            {
                animation.To = from;
                animation.From = to;
            }

            animation.Duration = new Duration(duration);

            return animation;
        }

        public static Storyboard CreateDoubleAnimation<T>(T control, bool modifier, double from, double to, TimeSpan duration, DependencyProperty property) where T : Control
        {
            return
             AnimationHelper.CreateDoubleAnimation<T>(control, modifier,
                (p, a) =>
                {
                    a.From = from;
                    a.To = to;
                },
                (p, a) =>
                {
                    a.From = to;
                    a.To = from;
                }, duration, property);
        }

        public static Storyboard CreateDoubleAnimation<T>(T control, bool modifier, Action<T, DoubleAnimation> onTrue, Action<T, DoubleAnimation> onFalse, TimeSpan duration, DependencyProperty property) where T : Control
        {
            if (control == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("control");

            DoubleAnimation panelAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();

            if (modifier)
            {
                if (onTrue != null)
                    onTrue.Invoke(control, panelAnimation);

            }
            else
            {
                if (onFalse != null)
                    onFalse.Invoke(control, panelAnimation);
            }


            panelAnimation.Duration = new Duration(duration);

            Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();

            Storyboard.SetTargetName(panelAnimation, control.Name);

            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(panelAnimation, new PropertyPath(property));

            sb.Children.Add(panelAnimation);

            return sb;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!! Actually I was very close ... I had tried the ZIndex but did not get it to work. The missing part was a simple misunderstanding of how to add subitems to grid. I thought you had to define ColumnDefinitions and RowDefinitions to get it working. Adding subcontainers to main grid without specifying row or column made the difference. I also found the suggestion of opacity and minimal height to be very useful. That mimics the Windows 8 App Style very well.

Comment: Hi Guys, Im a little late to this  but I was wondering where you are referencing the following class / method from: AnimationHelper.CreateDoubleAnimation? I've look some for it but all I've been able to find for that class are in some third party projects...

Comment: @KeithVinson Hey, It was a class I wrote at the time.. it was nothing special just a class that wrapped the animations. From What I remember, its just wrapped this class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hi Steoates. Got it, I had seen that class when Googling so I'll just go the same way. Thanks for the post back...

Comment: @Steoates Awesome job! Any chance of adding your AnimationHelper class to the answer?

Comment: @DanSmith I did a bit of digging and finaly found it..see answer :)