# How to implement Win8 news app bar style menu in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-8, appbar

I am trying to wrap my head around how to implement, in WPF, a menu with the same type of look as the MS News app in win8.

Any ideas for a good starting point?

[image]

Comment: This will be good start for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030507/how-to-create-windows-8-style-app-bar-in-wpf

Comment: Thanks, that was a great startingpoit for the bars themself. I was actually firstly thinking of the menu itself. I am new to WPF, so I Wonder where to start if these menues should be dynamic. How to build the main and sub menues.